# Distinct on multiple columns of a table but with complex requirement

Tags: mysql, sql, database

My view(named view1) looks like this:

```
Sno |  Rno   |  Total  
1   |  2     |   5  
2   |  1     |   6  
3   |  4     |   5  
4   |  5     |   8
```

**`sno`**: sender number , **`rno`**: receiver number, **`total`**: number of messages sent from `sno` to `rno`

I should write a query such that the query should result in:

**case 1:** If we have records in the table in both directions i.e. 1 to 2 and 2 to 1 like in the above table, we should add both the counts and display them in a single row i.e. here

we will get 1  2   11   in the output (1-2 is 5 and 2-1 is 6)
Because we already have 1 2 11 in the output, our query should not include 2 1 11 in the output/result set.

**case 2:** If we have records that are just one direction i.e. here we have a record from 3 to 4 but we don't have a record from 4 to 3

In this case we have to just return 3  4  5 in the output.

Finally we need to union/combine results of both the cases and return it as the result.

I tried various ways but none of them returned the desired output. My query looks like this:

```
select a.sno,a.rno,a.total from view1 a where not exists(select * from view1 b where a.sno=b.rno and a.rno=b.sno) 
union
select a1.sno,a1.rno, (a1.total+b1.total) as total from view1 a1, view1 b1 where a1.sno=b1.rno and a1.rno=b1.sno;
```

Could you please take a look into it and see if you can help me figure out the correct solution?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I am using Mysql workbench.

Comment: That's not a DBMS, that's a SQL client. But as that can only work with MySQL it's safe to assume you are using MySQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a self `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT a.Sno
      ,a.Rno
      ,a.Total + COALESCE(b.Total,0) AS Total
FROM Table1 a
LEFT JOIN Table1 b
 ON a.Sno = b.Rno
 AND a.Rno = b.Sno
WHERE a.Sno < a.Rno
   OR b.Rno IS NULL
```

**Demo:** [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3adbf/2/0)

**Explanation:**  The idea here is that you are joining records that have swapped `Rno` and `Sno` values, so you can get the `Total` from each combination on the same line.  We use a `LEFT JOIN` to not exclude records, and we use `WHERE` criteria to prevent the swapped records appearing along with their counterpart, as well as including any without a counterpart who happen to have `Sno` > `Rno`.

**Note:** I did this with SQL Server, but it should work across DBMS.

**Update:** Based on your comment, it appears you don't have distinct pairs of `Sno`/`Rno` values in your table, you can fix this either by `DISTINCT` or by aggregating prior to using the above query, depending on desired output:

```
SELECT a.Sno
      ,a.Rno
      ,a.Total + COALESCE(b.Total,0) AS Total
FROM (SELECT Sno,Rno,SUM(Total) AS Total   --Or `SELECT DISTINCT Sno,Rno,Total` and remove `GROUP BY`
              FROM Table1
              GROUP BY Sno,Rno) a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Sno,Rno,SUM(Total) AS Total   --Or `SELECT DISTINCT Sno,Rno,Total` and remove `GROUP BY`
              FROM Table1
              GROUP BY Sno,Rno) b
 ON a.Sno = b.Rno
 AND a.Rno = b.Sno
WHERE a.Sno < a.Rno
   OR b.Rno IS NULL
```

Ideally perform this aggregation/unique list pull into a table rather than doing a self-join on subqueries if you have a large table.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am running your query now and waiting for it to complete execution.

Comment: Apparently I got the wrong output for some reason. I got a row 1 | 17 | 3 for more than 5 times. I should be getting only one row for a specific sno and rno.

Comment: @PrasadReddyMendu Based on the sample I thought you had a distinct list, you need to feed the above query a table that has distinct `Sno`/`Rno` pairs. See update, you need either to aggregate or pull distinct values.

Comment: My actual view contains thousands of rows, so there is something wrong in the output. It's probably because I used group by date when creating that view. Let me take a look at it and get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: Your new query worked like magic and solved my problem! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**When I posted my answer the question wasn't tagged as MySQL. The solution below won't work with MySQL (not in this form at least).**

If the DBMS you're using is MS SQL Server I think this query should do what you want:

```
SELECT v1.Sno, v1.Rno, v1.Total + ISNULL(oa.Total,0) AS Total
FROM View1 v1
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT Sno,Rno,Total 
    FROM View1 v2 
    WHERE v1.Sno=v2.Rno AND v2.Sno = v1.Rno
    ) oa
WHERE v1.Sno < v1.Rno
```

The result will be:

```
Sno         Rno         Total
----------- ----------- -----------
1           2           11
3           4           5
4           5           8
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/57e54/1)

Comment: Why the outer apply? Wouldn't a simple `left join` do the same thing?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes I guess it will. The reason I used the outer apply was simply that it was the first solution to enter my mind. Plus I think it might be a tiny bit faster (based on what I've read, not tried in this case).